# POST to /jobs/executions doesn't respond with an execution Id?

Tags: spring-xd

I've integrated my application with spring XD through the REST API.
I have a job def set up and deployed for each datasource (my module is jdbc related) and then launch specific jobs using the appropriate job def as a template with jobParameters provided in the POST request, containing criteria unique to that job run.

I then expected my REST client to be able to poll for metrics related to the job, it just initialized, but for such calls jobExecutionId is needed and the client doesn't have this value, only the jobName which is of course not unique.

I would have expected POST to /jobs/executions to respond with an executionId, the fact that it doesn't makes me question the way I'm using xd.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you; this seems to be an oversight...

```
/**
 * Send the request to launch Job. Job has to be deployed first.
 *
 * @param name the name of the job
 * @param jobParameters the job parameters in JSON string
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "jobname")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void launchJob(@RequestParam("jobname") String name, @RequestParam(required = false) String jobParameters) {
    ...
}
```

I can see the problem; we'd need to somehow feed the job execution back to the controller method (right now the there's no result from the launch request).

There is a work-around...

Use a job execution tap to dump the job execution to some sink; see the [job event tap documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_retrieve_job_notifications).

```
xd:>stream create --name jobex --definition "tap:job:myJob.job > file --name=exec --dir=/tmp" --deploy
```

This will write jobExecution information to /tmp/exec.out which you can monitor (instead of polling the REST API).

If you are in distributed mode, you could dump the data to a Redis (or similar) sink.

But I agree, it would be better if the launch returned the id.

Please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD).

Comment: Actually having glanced through the documentation I still don't get how the event tap provides jobExecution information specific to the instance just spawned in the POST request. If the jobname refers to the definition and there are 2 instances, with specific jobParamaters, each spawned by a different client how do they each get the appropriate metrics from the sink?

Comment: The `JobExecution` object captured by the tap contains the `jobParameters` which can be used for correlation; dump them to some persistent store you can query. I agree it's not ideal; I was just suggesting a work-around for the current situation. We are looking at providing a proper solution as part of some other work; watch [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2765) if you want to follow progress.

Comment: `stream create --name xmlexport1events --definition "tap:job:xmlexport1.job > jdbc --initializeDatabase=true" --deploy` results in xmlexport1events table created in xdjob db but no records are created because of `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution cannot be cast to java.lang.String` - I guess that is the attempt to insert the playload

Comment: Yeah, if you're going to dump it to a DB, you'll need to do some transformation on it.